# Set titles for the subplots, indicating the generating function (linear/exponential)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, title, subplot

1. Plot both the exponential and the linear function as scatter plots in respective subplots (i.e. in one figure)!
2. Set labels for both   and   axes.
3. Set a title for the figure (pick a large font size).
4. Set titles for the subplots, indicating the generating function (linear/exponential).

My code is as follows:

```
X = np.linspace(0,1,25)
Y_linear = 0.2 + X * 0.3
Y_exponential = 0.2 + 0.5 * X**2

#1
plt.plot (Y_linear_noisy)
plt.plot(Y_exponential_noisy)

#2and3
plt.title("GRAPH 1"), plt.xlabel("x"), plt.ylabel("y")

#4
plt.plot(Y_linear_noisy)
plt.title(Y_linear_noisy)
plt.plot (Y_exponential_noisy)
plt.title(Y_exponential_noisy)
```

I don't understand how to do point 4. If I write `plt.plot` it modifies the title at the top of the graph.

Comment: Why the `Matlab` tag? Did you mean `Matplotlib`?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created two separate subplots within one figure in your code.  Furthermore, for some reason, your question requires scatter plots, not line plots.  Here is how you do it. The comments in the code clarify each step:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(0,1,25)
Y_linear = 0.2 + X * 0.3
Y_exponential = 0.2 + 0.5 * X**2

fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(2,1)#create two subplots within one figure in a vertical column

ax1.scatter(X, Y_linear) #create a scatter subplot
ax1.set(xlabel ='x', ylabel = 'y = 0.3x + 0.2') #set x and y labels for subplot
ax1.set_title('Linear Graph', y=1.0, pad= -20) #set subplot title

ax2.scatter(X, Y_exponential)
ax2.set(xlabel ='x', ylabel = 'y = 0.5x^2 + 0.2')
ax2.set_title('Quadratic Graph', y=1.0, pad= -20)

plt.suptitle("Linear vs. Quadratic Comparison", fontsize = 20) #set super tititle for figure at larger font

plt.show()
```

[image]